# How to add MAVEN SHADE plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-shade-plugin

I have a maven project in eclipse. I was able to create the jar using maven build. Now I am trying to create jar using maven shade. But how do I add it in eclipse? I don't see any installation on the website. All tutorials show the edited pom.xml with maven shade tags.

I am missing something here. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Shade Plugin is a plugin for Maven, and not for Eclipse. If you include the plugin in your POM file as per the tutorials and examples (or configured to your needs) then Maven will download the plugin for itself to create the uber-jar with repacked dependencies.